# Difference between these two query implementations of inner joining a table with a lookup table?

Tags: join, query, table

I've been learning querying and I've come across the concept of `inner joining`

Where this query inner joins the columns `departmentId` from `employee` and `department` tables and displays the value of `department`.

```
select employeeId, employee, housing, department from employee e inner join department d
on e.departmentId = d.departmentId
```

And this another implementation of inner joining that I found out looks much simpler and easier to memorize

```
select employeeId, employee, housing, department from employee e, department d

where e.departmentId = d.departmentId
```

The output is precisely the same in both queries. I'm wondering if there's something that I'm not aware of that makes the former one more popularly used for inner joining than the latter.

Comment: See [@AaronBertrand on Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 0):

The last one

```
select employeeId, employee, housing, department from employee e, department d    
where e.departmentId = d.departmentId
```

Is old school and makes only a cross join

The result is the same of course for both query, but today JOINS are used, with LEFT, INNER RIGHT and CROSS JOIN as examples.

So you can see in one glance what the code writer wants to happen.

Starting Joining more and more tables, you can quite easily control what data will be in the result set.

If  you add 5 and 7 more tables to your SELECT query, you will notice oz gets quite easy very complicated, to filter all unwanted rows from the CROSS JOINs

While with JOINs you can add on tables after another and check if all data are there you need, which makes it easier to debug complicated queries.

When you post code here and you use comma separated tables, you get a frown and a reminder to switch to joins.